# Does FFMPEG support user data section injection when encoding?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

The MPEG and H.264 standards both define a mechanism for the injection of an arbitrary metadata stream into video frames. I've google'd a bit and am unable to determine if FFMPEG supports this. Does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not support this. That said, it really isn't that hard to implement this yourself and inject the metadata in to the encoded frames post encoding.